# Javascript: creating a array of objects inside a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code in Javascript:

```
function Camada(nome) {
  Camada.prototype.nome = nome;
  Camada.prototype.desenhar = function () {
  };
};

var camadas = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var camada = new Camada('nome' + i);
  camadas[i] = camada;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(camadas[i]);
}
```

But this always prints 10 times the last object Camada, the problem looks like that camadas is keeping a reference to the var camada;

How can I solve this kind of problem using a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue with your code is that you're assigning to `Camada.prototype` in a constructor. Use `this` instead.

The difference is that assigning to prototype will make this property common among all the instances of Camada. Assigning to `this` will make it a property of the given instance only (which is what you want).

Difference between `prototype` and `this` is explained pretty well in [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript).

Try this:

```
function Camada(nome) {
    // Since you're using Camada as a constructor, you can use 'this'
    // and assign new objects properties to it.
    this.nome = nome;
    this.desenhar = function () {};
};

var camadas = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var camada = new Camada('nome' + i);
    camadas[i] = camada;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(camadas[i].nome);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer? What roll is the wrapped function play?

Comment: Why do they need closure in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Because in the constructor for Camada you are changing the prototype.
The prototype is like the class, and is shared by all Camadas.

This should be what you're after:

```
function Camada(nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.desenhar = function () { };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your **nome** to the prototype. This means each time the constructor is called, it overwrites this property, and effects all instances.

Do not pass the **nome** value up to the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor you want to assign the param to the class property:

```
function Camada(nome) {
  this.nome = nome;
};
```